# Average values on group items using Mongo Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to group a collection and then compute the average on one field of the groups.

I setup my db and contents like this:

```
use testdb
db.bla.insert({"service": "A", "tet": "1"})
db.bla.insert({"service": "A", "tet": "100"})
db.bla.insert({"service": "A", "tet": "150"})
db.bla.insert({"service": "B", "tet": "10"})
db.bla.insert({"service": "B", "tet": "20"})
db.bla.insert({"service": "B", "tet": "25"})
```

Now I want the number of all services "A" and "B" and the average tet for all services "A" and "B".
I tried this:

```
db.bla.aggregate( { "$group": { _id: "$service", requests: { $sum:1}, averagetet: { $avg: "$tet"}}})
```

But that always gives me "0" for the average values.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using string values on `tet` field

```
db.bla.insert({"service": "B", "tet": "25"}) //this quotes creates a String value.
```

You have to insert using numbers, as follows:

```
db.bla.insert({"service": "B", "tet": 25})
```

Inserting the correct values, MongoDB gives the correct average of `tet` field.

```
db.bla.insert({"service": "A", "tet": 1})
db.bla.insert({"service": "A", "tet": 100})
db.bla.insert({"service": "A", "tet": 150})
db.bla.insert({"service": "B", "tet": 10})
db.bla.insert({"service": "B", "tet": 20})
db.bla.insert({"service": "B", "tet": 25})

db.bla.aggregate( { "$group": { _id: "$service", requests: { $sum:1}, averagetet: { $avg: "$tet"}}})
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": "B",
      "requests": 3,
      "averagetet": 18.333333333333332
    },
    {
      "_id": "A",
      "requests": 3,
      "averagetet": 83.66666666666667
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: how can i find the average number of requests per _id?

Comment: You only need to add, after the first $group, another group like "$group:{_id:null, avgreq:{$avg:"$requests"}}". Take into account that you can't take the avg tet per id, and the global avg requests in the same query.